# Parsing Hierarchy defined by codes

Tags: algorithm, file, parsing, recursion, hierarchy

I'm working on parsing a plain text file with a sort of hierarchical structure.
I know that some sort of recursive descendant algorithm should be able to help with this. But I have no experience on this.

**SAMPLE FILE:**

```
862,"ObjectName"
863,"ObjectType"
864,5      //This code has 5 items with the code 2 
    2,Item1
        5,"SetNameItem1"
    2,Item2
        5,"SetNameItem2"
    2,Item3
        543,5             //Item 3 has 5 Subelements under the code 543
            "subItemElement1"
            "subItemElement2"
            "subItemElement3"
            "subItemElement4"
            "subItemElement5"
        181,"543_AliasName"
        175,
        181,0
        182,
    2,Item4
        543,8         //Item 4 has 8 Subelements (no code to identify them) under the code 543
            "subItemElement1"
            "subItemElement2"
            "subItemElement3"
            "subItemElement4"
            "subItemElement5"
            "subItemElement6"
            "subItemElement7"
            "subItemElement8"
        181,"543_AliasName"
        175,
        182,0
    2,Item5
        5,"SetNameItem5"
234,"Property2"
233,"Property3"
238,"Property8"
```

**I'd like to store this in a tree or other hierarchical structure that will look like:**

```
**Level1:** 846

**Level 2:** Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4,Item6,Item6

**Level3:** Item1 {2="Setname"}, Item2 {2,SetName}, Item3 {{543={subelement1,subelement2,subelement3,...},181="543_AliasName",175="",181=0,182=0}, etc.

**Level4:** etc
```

It is pretty difficult as code 864 needs to count for 5 occurrences of code 2, which can have a code 5 or a code 543 (that has a number of sub items; 5 in the example)

I thought of creating a reference tree with the codes and how they place in the hierarchy, then I would need an algorithm to match the code and see if it has children.

Any help, algorithm, direction would be highly appreciated.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Maybe recursive descent?

Comment: Are you sure that "Item 3 has 8 Subelements" ?

Comment: It looks simple enough for a line-based analysis, although I don't immediately get the part around _AliasName.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that on my comments. It was 5. Cheers mate. I'm investigating Recursive descent but it seems to be applied to parsers for formulas and compilers, It doesn't seem to be exactly the same. Need more research how it can be applicable.

Comment: Is the indentation fixed? Or does it sometimes depend?

Comment: The alias name just points out the that code 181 it is a property attribure that belongs to the subitem (in this case, Item3), the hierarchy is represented by the identation, that is what I tried to replicate, however in the source files, there is no identation.

Comment: I don't understand the file format. You specify as output `Item1 {2="Setname"}, Item2 {2,SetName}` while both `Item1` and `Item2` have the same data in the input file? Secondly, you sometimes encode an alias as `"543_AliasName"` and sometimes like `543_AliasName`

Comment: The data isn't so important as the code hierarchy. What's important is that code 864 can have "children" of codes 2. Code 2 can have children of the type/code 5, 543,181,182,175. Can have them all or just some of them. Code 543 can have "string items" and the quantiy is defined on the right side of the comma. I tried to put "" on string items to clarify. What I mean by aliasname is just one of the properties that describe 2,Item3 and 2,Item4 in this example. Thanks mate

Comment: @DataAnalyst1: The point of an example is to elucidate. Typos in the example confuse, which is the opposite. As a courtesy to whoever might try to help you with the problem, please proof-read and correct the example. Eg. "//This code has 6 items with the code 6" => "5 items with the code 864", no? And not 846 as in your example result. Speaking of which, what happened to the codes 862 and 863? Etc...

Comment: Hi Rici, Thanks I'm trying to clean the example up but obviously a few lines have not come as clear as I thought and made few typos. Sorry for that. The main thing is that the source lines hierarchy are idented by ME to indicate such. It doesn't look like that in the source files. So first level are codes ie: 862,863,864,234,233,238, second: 2, third: 5,543,181,175,182.   That is just the deepness but the dependency is defined by the immediate upper item in hierarchy. I will recheck my sample, as I am trying to make it easier to comprehend given that the source looks much worse. Thanks!